# which is preferable method copy() or clone() in java

Tags: java, copy, clone

I have a requirement where I need to generate Object from existed object. I am not able to select the which method is used either clone() or copy().

Situation is if user click the button say Copy/Clone I need to generate the new Employee object which is having existed Employee data.

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: There is no `copy()` method in `Object` class at all.

Comment: The best practices are contructor copy.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Clonable interface when defining the class, create a clone function with return type `Object`, this function shall throw `CloneNotSupportedException` and shall return the clone :

```
public class YourClass implements Cloneable{
    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }
}
```

and when you create the object, use the clone function as follows :

```
YourClass obj = new YourClass();
YourClass objCopy = (YourClass) obj.clone();
```

Here is a [reference](http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/11/08/a-guide-to-object-cloning-in-java/) you can benefit from.

**EDIT**

You can also use copy constructor which is a better approach than clone :

```
class YourClass {
  private String dummy;

  public YourClass (YourClass another) {
    this.dummy = another.dummy; 
  }
}
```

Your call

```
YourClass class1 = new YourClass();
YourClass clone = new YourClass(class1);
```

Comment: I guess copy constructor shall resolve all of this..